# как вызвать функцию в формате String

Tags: firebase, flutter

я получаю изображение с помощью класса

```
class ImageLoader extends StatefulWidget{
  final String imageBytes;
  final Brand brand;

  const ImageLoader({Key key, this.imageBytes, this.brand}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, index){
    _ImageLoaderState();
  }

  @override
  _ImageLoaderState createState() => _ImageLoaderState();
}

class _ImageLoaderState extends State<ImageLoader> {

  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(
      storageBucket: 'gs://any.appspot.com');

  String errorMsg;
  String imageBytes;

  _ImageLoaderState() {
    storage.ref().child('images/image.jpeg').getDownloadURL().then((url) =>
        setState(() {
          imageBytes = url;
        })
    ).catchError((e) =>
        setState(() {
          errorMsg = e.error;
        })
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    imageBytes = widget.imageBytes;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Image.network(imageBytes, fit: BoxFit.fill,));
  }
}
```

Как я могу вызвать изображение использую файл данных?

вызов пути изображения у меня выглядит так `'${brand.model[0].model_image.image}'`

возвращает путь к изображению в формате **images/folder/image.jpeg**

когда я пытаюсь добавить `${brand.model[0].model_image.image}` в child `storage.ref().child('images/image.jpeg').getDownloadURL().then((url)` получаю ошибку brand не инициализирована, но когда я пытаюсь инициализировать brand, то получаю (url = null)

в общем, я пытаюсь получить `'gs://any.appspot.com' + '${brand.model[0].model_image.image}'` то есть ссылку на конкретное изображение, чтобы мой ListView.builder показывал изображения с учетом индекса

спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: Вы хотите в `_ComparePageState` передать `'gs://lalala.appspot.com'`? Вопрос не понятный...

Comment: сейчас проблема уже немного в другом. посмотрите, пожалуйста этот вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64304633/how-to-call-image-from-firebase-storage-with-index-by-data-file либо же для вашего удобства я могу обновить этот вопрос

Comment: Лучше обновить вопрос, либо этот закрыть и создать новый.

Comment: обновил вопрос, надеюсь описал понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее должно быть так:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: brand.lenght,
  itemBuilder: (c, i) => ImageLoader(brand.model[i]),
)

...

class ImageLoader extends StatefulWidget{
  final BrandModel model;

  const ImageLoader(this.model, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageLoaderState createState() => _ImageLoaderState();
}

class _ImageLoaderState extends State<ImageLoader> {
  final FirebaseStorage storage;

  String errorMsg;
  String image;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://any.appspot.com');
    storage.ref().child(widget.model.model_image.image).getDownloadURL().then((url) =>
        setState(() {
          image = url;
        })
    ).catchError((e) =>
        setState(() {
          errorMsg = e.error;
        })
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Image.network(image, fit: BoxFit.fill,));
  }
}
```

Comment: ваш код явно преобладает правильным направлением, я немного его видоизменил, чтобы он работал в условиях моих функций, но я получаю ошибку `type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Brand'  случайно не знаете в чем кроется проблема и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вместо объекта с типом Brand передать объект с типом String

Comment: я пытаюсь вызвать так  `Widget _buildCarouselItem(BuildContext context, int carouselIndex, index) {
      return ImageLoader(brand.model[0].model_image.image);
  }` при `storage.ref().child(widget.brand.model[0].model_image.image).getDownloadURL().then((url) =>` тогда появляется ошибка **Class 'List<Ilximage>' has no instance getter 'image'.
Receiver: Instance(length:5) of '_GrowableList'
Tried calling: image** как я понимаю нужно присвоить index но я не могу присвоить индекс здесь `storage.ref().child(widget.brand.model[0].model_image.image).getDownloadURL().then((url) =>`

Comment: если присвоить его к вызову класса то появляется ошибка которую я описал в комментарии к вашему коду

Comment: Вы явно путаете типы данных и не понимаете что хотите сделать. Зачем вы пытаетесь его вызвать через метод? Что значит присвоить index?

Comment: у меня есть файл с данными которые я получаю с помощью brand.model[0].model_image[index].image в этом случае я получаю путь к файлу с учетом индекса, то есть мой ListView.builder будет строить столько контейнеров сколько в файле есть путей к изображениям, я хочу получать url + путь к изображениям с помощью индекса, чтобы получать все изображения по отдельности. может, я не совсем понимаю, как можно это осуществить. я не совсем понял почему вы вызываете класс так ImageLoader(brand.model[i])

Comment: `ImageLoader(brand.model[i])` я вызвал чтобы передать конкретную модель по индексу. `i` я получил из `ListView.builder` так как он через `itemCount: brand.lenght,` знает сколько всего ему нужно элементов для построения списка. Сам `ImageLoader` является виджетом, по этому не обязательно делать его вызов через метод. Замете я передовал конкретную модель а не список моделей, чтобы было удобно его использовать в `storage.ref().child()`.

Comment: Вы также можете передать список, но тогда вам придется придумать как пройтись по нему и вывести все элементы в рамках одного виджета. Также я рекомендую вам почитать документация по [Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour) и [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui), так как у вас низкий уровень знаний. Вместо того чтобы правильно решить проблему вы пытаетесь создать велосипед, думаю после ознакомления с документацией вы сам сможете решить данную проблему более легким способом.

Comment: хорошо, я перечитаю документацию, возможно, я смогу найти там ответы на то, что сейчас я не могу понять, спасибо за вашу помощь, оставляю ваш ответ, как верный